# kendo view model change event only for user changes

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo view model and am trying to detect user changes on the page so that I can warn them if they're about to navigate away without saving (using an onbeforeunload event handler).  I bind to the view model change event to set a "changed" boolean to true.  However, after the document.ready is finished, many  view model fields asynchronously load from their data sources, triggering change events that I can't distinguish from user changes.  Is there some way to detect when all fields are done retrieving their data so that I don't mistake their binding updates as user changes?

```
<script>
    var myViewModel = kendo.observable({
        someField: "testing",
        //...Other fields with data sources that get filled in asynchronously
        //Problem is that these are bound to fields in html and trigger change event
        changed: false,
        loading: false,
        fetch: function () {
            this.set("loading", true);
            //...
            this.set("loading", false);
        }
    });
</script>

<div id="myView">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: someField" class="k-textbox" />
    <!--Other fields bound to fields in myViewModel-->
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        myViewModel.fetch().then(function () {
            kendo.bind($("#myView"), myViewModel);
        }, function (error) {
        });
    });

    myViewModel.bind("change", function (e) {
        if (myViewModel.loading === false) {
            myViewModel.changed = true;
        }
    });

    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        if (myViewModel.changed) {
            return "You haven't saved your changes!";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Consider returning a promise from the methods used to get the data?